# TCL top level disabling parent window not working in OpenSuse

Tags: window, parent, opensuse, disable, toplevel

I'm working on some TCL scripts for my work. The goal is to make them working on both Window and Linux OS (OpenSuse). I have some scripts opening a top level. After that they disable the parent window with the instruction

```
wm attributes . -disabled True
```

Under Windows everything works fine, the parent is disabled and the user can act only on the top level.
When running the same code under OpenSuse instead the code crashes because the option -disabled is not available.

I tried to use the option -type as described on the wm manual page but I haven't been able to find anything that can make the code working in OpenSuse the same way it works on Windows.
Does anybody know what's th4e equivalent code to be used on Linux machines to do the same thing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Solved by using tcl "grab" command.